# Есть ли какая-то разница между BeginInvoke на Control'е и BeginInvoke на делегате?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Собственно, вопрос.

Интересует то, что делают ли они в тоности одинаковую работу, либо где-то помимо асинхронной операции решаются еще какие-то задачи.

Вот заметил, что если я на Control вызываю BeginInvoke, то GUI зависает, пока не будет выполнено действие там, в то время, как если вызвать его на делегате, то выполняется "параллельно" 2 действия.

Comment: `BeginInvoke на делегате` выполняет делегат,  `BeginInvoke на Control'е` выполняет код в потоке, в котором был создан контрол. Или вы про что спрашиваете?